# how to update TABLE FK in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have problem with my project php,
I can't update a particular table in MySQL, I don't know what wrong with this code:

```
<?php defined('login') or die('Restricted access'); $id_o_u_a = $_GET['id_o_u_a']; if(!empty($id_o_u_a)){ $query = $koneksi->query("select *from organisasiumatanggota where id_o_u_a='$id_o_u_a'"); $data  $query>fetch_array();extract($data);}?><style type="text/css"media="screen">.judul_input{font-weight: bold; }#form_input tr{height:45px;}</style>
        <div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="index.php?page=prosesubahorganisasiumatanggota">
      <table width="60%" id="form_input">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <tr>
            <td class="judul_input">Nama</td>
            <input name="id_organisasi" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_o_u_a;?>" >
            <td> <select name="nama" class="form-control">
            <?php
            $query = $koneksi->query("select *from umatanggota order by id desc");
              if($query->num_rows != 0){
                while($data = $query->fetch_array()){
                  echo "<option value=$data[id] >$data[nama]</option>";
                }
              }
            ?></td></select>              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="judul_input">Nama Organisasi</td>
            <td> <select name="id_organisasi" class="form-control">
            <?php
            $query = $koneksi->query("select *from organisasi order by id_organisasi desc");
              if($query->num_rows != 0){
                while($data = $query->fetch_array()){
                  echo "<option value=$data[id_organisasi] >$data[nama_organisasi]</option>";
                }
              }
            ?></td></select>              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="judul_input">Nama Jabatan</td>
              <td> <select name="id_organisasi" class="form-control">
              <?php
              $query = $koneksi->query("select *from jabatan order by id_jabatan desc");
                if($query->num_rows != 0){
                  while($data = $query->fetch_array()){
                    echo "<option value=$data[id_jabatan] >$data[jns_jabatan]</option>";
                  }
                }
              ?></td></select>              </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SIMPAN" name="submit">
</form>
```

this is my code to process sql data

```
<?php
 defined('login') or die('Restricted access');
extract($_POST); 
if(empty($id)){
header("location:index.php?page=tambahorganisasiumatanggota&pesan=data masih kosong"); 
exit;}
$query = $koneksi->query("update organisasiumatanggota set id='$id', id_organisasi='$id_organisasi', id_jabatan='$id_jabatan' where id_o_u_a='$id_o_u_a'") or die(mysqli_error()); if($query){
  header("location:index.php?page=organisasiumatanggota&pesan=data sudah disimpan");
  exit;
}else{
  header("location:index.php?page=tambahorganisasiumatanggota&pesan=data gagal disimpan");
  exit;
}?>
```

Comment: what error your getting ?

Comment: data in table umatanggota does not change, there is an error data is still empty, but I've chosen the data to be changed

Comment: There seems to be no POST-value 'id' in the form.